# Get data week (also month) wise from the giver year

Tags: sql, db2

I want to get data week (also month) wise from the giver year in DB2.

e.g. `select * From tableName where week=10 or week=40;`

Please help to wrie SQL in DB2.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `WEEK_ISO()` function which returns integer value 1-53

```
select * From tableName where WEEK_ISO(yearValue)=10 or WEEK_ISO(yearValue)=40;
```

[Documentation here](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/dzichelp/v2r2/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db2z9.doc.sqlref/src/tpc/db2z_bif_weekiso.htm)

Answer (score 0):

I have used folling SQL to get data month and weekwise. Thanks you friend for support.

-- Calculate data week wise --

```
SELECT  WEEK_ISO(login_datetime) AS Week, YEAR(login_datetime) AS Year
FROM TableName 
WHERE login_datetime BETWEEN  '2012-01-01' AND '2013-12-31' 
GROUP BY WEEK_ISO(login_datetime), YEAR(login_date) 
ORDER BY YEAR(login_datetime), WEEK_ISO(login_datetime)
```

-- Calculate data month wise --

```
SELECT MONTH(login_datetime) AS Month, YEAR(login_datetime) AS Year
FROM TableName 
WHERE login_datetime BETWEEN '2012-01-01' AND '2013-12-31' 
GROUP BY MONTH(login_datetime), YEAR(login_datetime) 
ORDER BY YEAR(login_datetime), MONTH(login_datetime)
```

Comment: Learn how to format code for readability and display, please.  There were several syntax errors (corrected).  It's not recommended to use `BETWEEN` [with date/time/timestamps](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common) - or any type with a continuous range.  The use of functions in the `GROUP BY` and `ORDER BY` clauses means that part of the query can't use indices - a Calendar Table would be able to help here.